# How do I create a global list with multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, list

My plan is to that I want to hurry up my process that instead of checking one by one links, I would like to check all the links at the same time and have a global list where I append all the found links. And only print out once we find a new link.

I have created something like this but i'm getting stuck on how I can apply threading in my situation:

```
import time

def parseNewArticles():

    siteCatalog = ["https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03MfsHFjiuq1PInpgtEw0x_ctZKvA%3A1603437501435&source=hp&ei=vYOSX7u3F4PAa8qEpbgM&q=hello+world&oq=hello+world&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyBQguEMsBMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyAggAMgIILjICCAA6BwgjEOoCECc6CQgjEOoCECcQEzoECCMQJzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDOgQIABBDOgcILhBDEJMCOgUILhCxAzoKCC4QsQMQQxCTAjoECC4QQzoICC4QsQMQgwE6BQguEJMCOgQIABAKOgQILhAKOgcIABCxAxAKOgcIABAKEMsBUJMMWPQeYIgfaAVwAHgAgAHAAYgB9wiSAQQxMy4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj7icKVlsrsAhUD4BoKHUpCCccQ4dUDCAc&uact=5",
                   "https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01qENv3p5Dla2i8YR20XykwVN2DOA%3A1603437505803&ei=wYOSX-WMMK_rrgT73KqQCA&q=stackoverflow&oq=stackoverflow&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzICCAAyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgIIADIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBOgQILhAnOgUIABCxAzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BAgAEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6BAguEEM6BwguELEDEEM6AgguOgUILhCxA1DsMli3O2D1O2gAcAF4AIABZYgBlQeSAQQxMi4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwil8c6XlsrsAhWvtYsKHXuuCoIQ4dUDCA0&uact=5",
                   "https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=ALeKk017_VtlAFReIFyxqxp4dEQ0SVqFRg%3A1603437514396&ei=yoOSX4XNF4KEwPAPtOuZiAQ&q=weather&oq=weather&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywE6BAgAEEc6BAgjECc6BQgAELEDOgQIABBDOgIIADoHCAAQsQMQQzoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoICAAQsQMQgwE6AgguUIA8WIFBYK9BaABwAngAgAFaiAGyA5IBATaYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiF2tublsrsAhUCAhAIHbR1BkEQ4dUDCA0&uact=5"]
                   
    articelsLists = [] # Global List that I want to append from all the links above
    
    ### Here is where I want each link from siteCatalog to be in each threading ###
    
    while True:

        newArticleLists = # Will be a function that scrapes all the articles and adds it to a own list

        for articles in newArticleLists:
            if articles not in articelsLists:
                articelsLists.append(articles)
                print(f"[Found: {articles}]")
        
        time.sleep(600)
        
        else:
            print(f"[Total in list: {len(articelsLists)}]")
            time.sleep(600)
            continue
```

My question is how can I apply that each link has its own thread and append to a global list?

EDIT:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

articelsLists = []  # Global List

def get_new_article_lists(site):
    newArticleLists = list() # to extract articles from site
    for articles in newArticleLists:
        if articles not in articelsLists:
            articelsLists.append(articles)
            print(f"[Found: {articles}]")
            
    else:
        print(f"No new articles found!")
        
    time.sleep(600)
        
def parseNewArticles():

    siteCatalog = ["https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=blah", 
                   "https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=blahblah",
                   "https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=blahblahblah",]


    for site in siteCatalog):
        Thread(target=get_new_article_lists, args=(site, )).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a thread pool to retrieve the URLs and scrape the articles. Here, I am using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class from the `concurrent.futures` module. The most efficient way to detect/remove duplicate articles is to use a `set`:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import time


def get_article_list(url):
    """
    This function returns scrapes a URL and returns a list of articles
    """
    pass # for now


def parseNewArticles():
    

    siteCatalog = ["https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03MfsHFjiuq1PInpgtEw0x_ctZKvA%3A1603437501435&source=hp&ei=vYOSX7u3F4PAa8qEpbgM&q=hello+world&oq=hello+world&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyBQguEMsBMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyAggAMgIILjICCAA6BwgjEOoCECc6CQgjEOoCECcQEzoECCMQJzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDOgQIABBDOgcILhBDEJMCOgUILhCxAzoKCC4QsQMQQxCTAjoECC4QQzoICC4QsQMQgwE6BQguEJMCOgQIABAKOgQILhAKOgcIABCxAxAKOgcIABAKEMsBUJMMWPQeYIgfaAVwAHgAgAHAAYgB9wiSAQQxMy4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj7icKVlsrsAhUD4BoKHUpCCccQ4dUDCAc&uact=5",
                   "https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01qENv3p5Dla2i8YR20XykwVN2DOA%3A1603437505803&ei=wYOSX-WMMK_rrgT73KqQCA&q=stackoverflow&oq=stackoverflow&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzICCAAyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgIIADIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBOgQILhAnOgUIABCxAzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BAgAEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6BAguEEM6BwguELEDEEM6AgguOgUILhCxA1DsMli3O2D1O2gAcAF4AIABZYgBlQeSAQQxMi4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwil8c6XlsrsAhWvtYsKHXuuCoIQ4dUDCA0&uact=5",
                   "https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=ALeKk017_VtlAFReIFyxqxp4dEQ0SVqFRg%3A1603437514396&ei=yoOSX4XNF4KEwPAPtOuZiAQ&q=weather&oq=weather&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywEyBQgAEMsBMgUIABDLATIFCAAQywE6BAgAEEc6BAgjECc6BQgAELEDOgQIABBDOgIIADoHCAAQsQMQQzoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoICAAQsQMQgwE6AgguUIA8WIFBYK9BaABwAngAgAFaiAGyA5IBATaYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiF2tublsrsAhUCAhAIHbR1BkEQ4dUDCA0&uact=5"]

    MAX_THREADS_TO_EVER_USE = 100 #depends on many factors; you must experiemnent
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=min(len(siteCatalog), MAX_THREADS_TO_EVER_USE)) as executor:
        new_articles_set = set() # to remove duplicates
        while True:
            futures = [executor.submit(get_article_list, url) for url in siteCatalog]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                new_article_list = future.result()
                for new_article in new_article_list:
                    if new_article not in new_articles_set:
                        print(f'Found {new_article}')
                        new_articles_set.add(new_article) # there will be no duplicates in the set
            time.sleep(600)
```

Comment: Hello Booboo! Does this mean that it works the way that it does it one by one or does it work simultaneously? And if that case, where do I print if we find a new URL that we have not found before?

Comment: I updated the answer to print the new articles as they are found and to repeat every 600 seconds. Sorry about that.

Comment: nothing to sorry about! If you could please explain me, why is the reason you choose ThreadPoolExectuor over the threading or simultaneously? (Not sure if your example runs simultaneously ? )

Comment: This is the comment I posted to the answer that used threading without a thread pool: *Let's say siteCatalog had 5000 entries in it? Would you create 5000 threads? A "thread pool" is the better general solution.* The point is that using straight threading does not scale up; there is some maximum number of threads you want to create and process your URL requests or else performance will start to deteriorate. Let's say that number is 100 (it depends on many factors). Then you want the 100 threads to process the 5000 URL requests and that's how a thread pool works.

Comment: Oh so basically its like a limiter of having n threads so instead of spawning new, you use the n threads to process all the URL'S basically? The way you did the list however, Wouldn't it take more resources/longer time to do the way you check if the links already is in the list or not?

Comment: As far as "simultaneously", I do not know what function `get_article_list` does with the returned page after fetching. The pages will be fetched *concurrently* because threading is very good at overlapping I/O and/or URL fetching. It's not so good at overlapping Python code. So if there is a lot of Python CPU processing done on the returned page, it will not be done concurrently. But I suspect that the processing time is much smaller compared to the URL fetch time so threading is still a good choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223519/discussion-between-booboo-and-protractornewbie).

Answer (score 1):

As a simple or maybe naive approach, you can use python threading library.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

articelsLists = []  # Global List

def get_new_article_lists(site):
    newArticleLists = list() # to extract articles from site
    for articles in newArticleLists:
        if articles not in articelsLists:
            articelsLists.append(articles)
            print(f"[Found: {articles}]")
        else:
            print(f"[Total in list: {len(articelsLists)}]")
        
        time.sleep(600)
        
def parseNewArticles():

    siteCatalog = ["https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=blah", 
                   "https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=blahblah",
                   "https://www.google.se/search?sxsrf=blahblahblah",]


    threads = dict()
    for i, site in enumerate(siteCatalog):
        threads[i] = Thread(target=get_new_article_lists, args=(site, ))
        threads[i].start()

    try:
        for i in threads.keys():
            threads[i].join()
    except:
        # handle excptions
        pass
```

Comment: Hello! Hmm are you sure that we should have while True instead the threading.keys? Maybe you meant in the get_new_article_lists?

Comment: As I can see, you will get stuck in `While true` with the threads.join. Are you sure it should be there?

Comment: Hi, you're right. I've just edited it. what would happen in get_new_article_lists depends on you and how you extract articles

Comment: Exactly. One thing, wouldn't it make also more senseto do .join() after the .start() in the loop instead of having own threads.keys() ?

Comment: Actually why I called join() after starting threads is to tell the main thread(the main process) to not terminate until the threads execution is done. Surely you can test whether invoking join() in the first loop is okay or not, then you won't need dict(), just initialize a thread there

Comment: I have done a small update on my thread. I added a code snippet and it is a modification from your code. Would it make any sense to do the way I did that way?

Comment: Your `threads` variables is currently a `dict` with keys 0, 1, 2.  Why not just make this a `list` that you append your threads to?

Comment: Let's say `siteCatalog` had 5000 entries in it? Would you create 5000 threads? A "thread pool" is the better general solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that instead of using a separate worker for each URL, you create a pool of workers and have them run the downloads. You can scale up or down the number of workers (hence the concurrency) depending on your hardware and other requirement. Here's a stripped down implementation.

```
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

urls = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.yahoo.com', 'https://www.bing.com']*10

def download(url):
    print ("downloading {}".format(url))
    time.sleep(1)
    return "done"

def download_all(workers = 10):
    pool = ThreadPool(workers)
    results = pool.map(download, urls)
    print (results[:10])
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    download_all()
```

By changing the number of workers in the call to `download_all`, you can scale up or scale down your solution.

Comment: Intresting! Might I ask what is the advantage vs. threading? comapre to your solution?

Comment: Yes you may. This is StackOverflow after all. This is internally using `threading`. Just that it's a higher level abstraction. You're basically parallelising a task using a number of threads. That's traditionally done using a worker pool rather than spawning individual threads. If you had 10000 URLs and each took 2 seconds, you'd have 20,000 threads running at once which will lead to degradation. The worker pool allows you to compromise between parallelism and performance in an easy way.

Comment: You can also see how much cleaner and more readable it is.

Comment: It looks very nice and very intresting to implement, however how would it work for an example that im trying to do where I constantly want to check for new articles every 600 sec? if you might have an example of how it could look?